# NullPointerException when i call the write() method of BluetoothConnectionService object which sends my data to arduino via blueooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition

```
package com.example.ayushiagarwal.voice_app;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Ayushi Agarwal on 6/23/2017.
 */

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
    private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;
    public ArrayList<String> result;
    public char ch;

    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);

        mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
        mSpeakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVoiceInput();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startVoiceInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));

                }
                break;
            }

        }
        String str = TextUtils.join(" ", result);


        if (str.equals("turn on") || str.equals("turn off"))
            ch = 'a';

        else if (str.equals("one"))
            ch = '1';
        else if (str.equals("to"))
            ch = '2';
        else if (str.equals("three"))
            ch = '3';
        else if (str.equals("four"))
            ch = '4';
        else if (str.equals("five"))
            ch = '$';
        else if (str.equals("six"))
            ch = '6';
        else if (str.equals("seven"))
            ch = '7';
        else if (str.equals("eight"))
            ch = '8';
        else if (str.equals("nine"))
            ch = '9';
        else if (str.equals("zero"))
            ch = '0';
        else if (str.equals("volume up"))
            ch = '+';
        else if (str.equals("volume down"))
            ch = '-';
        else if (str.equals("channel up"))
            ch = '^';
        else if (str.equals("channel down"))
            ch = '}';
        else if (str.equals("mute"))
            ch = 'b';
        else if (str.equals("previous channel"))
            ch = 'n';
        else if (str.equals("channel list"))
            ch = '=';
        else if (str.equals("tools"))
            ch = '/';
        else if (str.equals("info"))
            ch = 'h';
        else if (str.equals("return"))
            ch = 's';
        else if (str.equals("exit"))
            ch = 'x';
        else if (str.equals("up"))
            ch = 'y';
        else if (str.equals("down"))
            ch = 'd';
        else if (str.equals("left"))
            ch = '.';
        else if (str.equals("right"))
            ch = ',';
        else if (str.equals("select"))
            ch = 'k';
        else if (str.equals("play"))
            ch = 'o';
        else if (str.equals("pause"))
            ch = 'i';
        else if (str.equals("forward"))
            ch = ']';
        else if (str.equals("reverse"))
            ch = '[';
        else if (str.equals("menu"))
            ch = 'm';

        else if (str.equals("source"))
            ch = '#';
        else if (str.equals("media"))
            ch = ':';
        else if (str.equals("hdmi"))
            ch = 'g';


        // byte[] bytes = new String(ch).getBytes();
        mBluetoothConnection=new BluetoothConnectionService(Activity2.this);
        mBluetoothConnection.write(ch);}

    }
```

I'm getting the error at the mBluetoothConnection.write(char) even though i initialized the object.

the error in the logcat is as :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ayushiagarwal.voice_app.BluetoothConnectionService$ConnectedThread.write(char)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                              at com.example.ayushiagarwal.voice_app.BluetoothConnectionService.write(BluetoothConnectionService.java:326)
>                                                                                              at com.example.ayushiagarwal.voice_app.Activity2.onActivityResult(Activity2.java:159)

this is my BluetoothConnectionService class:

```
 package com.example.ayushiagarwal.voice_app;

/**
 * Created by Ayushi Agarwal on 6/22/2017.
 */

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by User on 12/21/2016.
 */

public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";


    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    public String incomingMessage;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }




    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if (socket != null) {
                connected(socket, mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());

            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Trying fallback...");
                    mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, 2);
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection!");
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                    } catch (IOException e3) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e3.getMessage());
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            }
            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     * Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Connecting Bluetooth"
                , "Please Wait...", true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     * receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     **/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        public String incomingMessage;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(char msg) {
            String text = Character.toString(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(text.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(char)
     */
    public void write(char out) {
        //Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        //Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write

        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your device bluetooth connected to the arduino?

Comment: yes it is paired with the arduino bluetooth hc-05

Comment: Try this example. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

Comment: the problem is the app is crashing even though the chat object is initialized and the value to char is given through speech to text conversion , then what could be the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

After Java 7, resources are used with try-with-resource block.
You can use the same something like this.

```
  try (BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection=new 
         BluetoothConnectionService(Activity2.this)
   ){
      if(ch!=null)
      mBluetoothConnection.write(ch);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```